# Can we create a ajax form within a fieldset of another form?

Tags: ajax, forms, fieldset

Is this possible?

The ajax form's purpose is to serve as a selector for the main form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms cannot be nested.

Btw, you don't need a form for that purpose. Just send AJAX request without any form.

Put a select/set of radio buttons outside the form, assign `onchange` handler and in it do whatever you want. For example - send AJAX query and modify the form.

Comment: thanks. i tried moving it out of the form and it works! but still have to think of an alternative, as moving it to another part of the page doesn't fulfill the client's requirement